# giving group based permissions to users to access folders on S3 using aws java sdk

Tags: amazon-s3, directory-structure, aws-java-sdk

I have an application where i am saving data to amazon S3 . It will have a tree like folder structure(using "/" separator in key) . I want to give access of particular folder to a different user too ( view , add ,edit etc ) just like google drive ( a shared folder b/w multiple users). Mutiple users can view or update based on permissions .

How it can be done in S3 using the aws java sdk .(not using aws s3 policies from management console )
how it's done for google drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `s3:prefix` condition in the IAM policy to give access to specific folders.

For example, you want to give full access to the `shared` folder, you can have a permission like this one:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/shared",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/shared/*"
            ]
        },
```

By selectively allowing read/write permissions, you can give read/write rights to certain users.

You also give List permissions to the root and to the shared folder:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "shared/"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_home-directory-console.html